# Laravel 5.3 middleware guard not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, middleware

Recently I've upgraded to `Laravel 5.3` from `Laravel 5.2` and after that I've found the `Localization` middleware that I've created for setting user's language has stopped working, not sure why?

I am using `token` based `authentication`.

The middleware is as:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use PhpSpec\Exception\Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class Localization {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
       if(!Auth::guard()->guest())
       {
            if(!session('current_locale'))  {
                $localecode = Auth::guard($guard)->user()->getLocale();
                session('current_locale',empty ($localecode) ? 'en' : $localecode);
                \App::setLocale($localecode);
            }else{
                \App::setLocale(session('current_locale'));
            }
       }
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

And my `routes/api.php` is as:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/service/v1', 'middleware' => ['api'], 'guard' => 'api'], function(){
    Route::get("someUrlHere","SomeControler@SomeMethod");
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','localization','beforeMiddleware', 'afterApiCallMiddleware'], 'guard' => 'api'], function() {
        Route::get("SomeOtherUrlHere","SomeOtherControler@SomeOtherMethod");
    });
});
```

The `config/auth.php` is as:

```
<?php

return [
    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'email' => 'auth.emails.password',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],
];
```

The `app/Http/Kernal.php` is as:

```
<?php namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel {

    protected $middleware = [
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,  
        'Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors',

    ];

    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
    ];

    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic' => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',     
        'guest' => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'localization'=>'App\Http\Middleware\Localization',
        'afterMiddleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AfterMiddleware',
        'beforeMiddleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\BeforeMiddleware',
        'afterApiCallMiddleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AfterApiCall',
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ];

}
```

Each time calling the method I am finding the `$guard` is null in `handle()` method of the `Localization` middleware.

Comment: show your auth.php

Comment: OK. Let me post it.

Comment: @msonowal I've posted it.

Comment: Would you also mind posting your `app/Http/Kernel.php`?

Comment: did you tried changing 
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    by specifying $guard='api'

Comment: @RossWilson I've added ```Kernel.php```

Comment: @msonowal I don't think it will be good to have default value ```api``` to variable ```$guard``` because the same middleware I am using in ```routes\web.php``` too.

Comment: ok, but I just wanted to check whether it is working or not!, So, that we can know the cause

Comment: Yes it will work if you pass it statically. I have checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `$guard` is an additional param in the middleware you will have to pass it through manually. You should be able to do this be changing the value in your Route::group middleware array from:

```
'localization'
```

to:

```
'localization:api'
```

Hope this helps!